# Java 7 on OSX, how to run it?

Tags: java, osx-mavericks

I just installed Java 7 on OS X 10.9 from [here](http://www.java.com/en/download/mac_download.jsp?locale=en). However, when I run `java -version` I still get `1.6.0_65`. Also, in `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` I only see 1.6.0.jdk.

**How do I tell OS X to run Java 7?**

Comment: I found it here: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin... which is where it's supposed to live? Hmmmm

Answer (score 0):

The JRE7 installer only modifies `/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/` and `/Library/PreferencePanes/`. It does not modify `/System/Library/`, `/usr/bin/`, or `/Library/Java/`.

The `java` binary is in `/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java` like you said.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/ for more information.